# Movement of a partially filled oil tanker

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I came across the following question

- A partially filled oil tanker is being carried on a truck moving with constant-horizontal
  acceleration. What will happen to the level of oil?

which had the following answer:

-The level of oil will rise on the back side of the tank and fall on the front side

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in equilibrium, the back face and the front face of the container applies equal force to the oil. Since the oil is accelerating forward, the back of the container must push the oil harder. And as an adjustment ,the height of the oil rises towards the back to balance this extra force.

Comment: Does there exist any mathematical proof of such problems?

Comment: If you write the force balance equations properly, you can mathematically find the difference in height between the front and back. I hope this is what you meant by 'mathematical proof'. If you are unsure about how to write the force equations ,take a look at https://blog.myrank.co.in/pressure-in-case-of-accelerating-fluid/